# Simple Scheme, squaring all elements in a list

Tags: scheme

Okay, I'm new to Scheme and I thought I understood it, but got confused on this problem.  I want to square all the elements of a list.  So, (mapsq '(1 2 3)) returns (list 1 4 9).

my code:

```
(define mapsq
  (lambda (ls)
    (cond ((null? ls) 0)
          (else (cons (car ls) (car ls))
                (mapsq (cdr ls)))))))
```

Comment: And the problem with your code is...?

Comment: sorry,  I get an error   cons: second argument must be a list, but received 9 and 0

Comment: Since there are no elements in the empty list, (mapsq '()) is '(). In the code, you have a 0 in stead of '().

Answer (score 3):

In a practical (non-academic) context, this problem can be easily solved by using the `map` procedure:

```
(define mapsq
  (lambda (ls)
    (map (lambda (x) (* x x))
         ls)))
```

Of course, if this is homework and you need to implement the solution from scratch, I shouldn't spoon-feed the answer. Better find out the solution by yourself, filling-in the blanks:

```
(define mapsq
  (lambda (ls)
    (cond ((null? ls)               ; If the list is empty
           <???>)                   ; ... then return the empty list.
          (else                     ; Otherwise
           (cons (* <???> <???>)    ; ... square the first element in the list
                 (mapsq <???>)))))) ; ... and advance the recursion.
```

There are two problems in your solution: first, the base case should not return `0` - if we're building a list as an answer, then you must return the empty list. Second, in the recursive step you aren't actually squaring the current element in the list - to do that just multiply it by itself with the `*` operator.

Comment: Thanks, I figured my problem out.  In my base case I was returning a 0 when it should have been '().

Comment: @user1763943 That, and the fact that you weren't actually _squaring_ the current element in the list (by multiplying it by itself). Welcome to StackOverflow! please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful for you by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it like this:

```
(define (mapsq xs)
  (define (square x) (* x x))
  (map square xs))
```

Or this:

```
(define (mapsq xs)
  (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) xs))
```

Or maybe like this:

```
(define (mapsq xs)
  (let loop ((xs xs) (sqs '()))
    (if (null? xs)
        (reverse sqs)
        (loop (cdr xs) (cons (* (car xs) (car xs)) sqs)))))
```

Or even like this:

```
(define (mapsq xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      '()
      (cons (* (car xs) (car xs)) (mapsq (cdr xs)))))
```

My preference would be the first option. The second option is shorter, but the auxiliary function makes the first option easier to read. I would probably not use either the third or fourth options.

By the way, the solution by laser_wizard doesn't work, either.

I notice that you're new here. If you like an answer, click the up arrow next to the answer so the person who gave the answer gets points; this mark also lets the community of readers know that there is something of value in the answer. Once you have an answer that you are confident is correct, click the check mark next to the answer; that also gives points to the person that gave the answer, and more importantly lets other readers know that you believe this answer most correctly addresses your question.

Comment: The OP [doesn't have enough rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) to upvote your post! They can, of course, accept an answer, and should, assuming they are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (mapsq xs)
  (map * xs xs))

> (mapsq '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(1 4 9 16 25)
```